# Sound does not work in many apps after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. I'm also trying to avoid Pulseaudio at all costs

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Basically, I'm trying to get everything to use ALSA like I had on my old OS. Now with Ubuntu 18.04, I have some offline apps that sound great with ALSA but others such as firefox or Audacity that have no sound at all. I read from some online forums that you can get Alsa to run as the default sound device but I couldn't figure out how to edit the config. I was only able to figure out how to disable Pulseaudio by setting the respawn to no and removing the ;. Anything beyond that was too confusing for me to understand but I really don't want to be stuck without sound forever. Youtube and Audacity are important to me and I need to use them. Please help...

Comment: Firefox dropped ALSA support years ago to my knowledge (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355092) as it hit many Lubuntu 16.04 LTS users hard (Lubuntu didn't use pulse audio) so you may have to use a different browser there.

Comment: there is no easy way to make firefox use ALSA. impossible to meet both requirements to avoid pulseaudio and not too confusing